# How can i create custom component dynamically by string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi I need to help with my method for creating list of custom components.
This method has same logic for 4 components (Package,Theme,Part, Knowledges). Only one thing i have to change is component which i pushing to list.

I tried something like this, but this throw weird error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: <Package /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

```
export class SubjectDashboardUtils {
    /**
     * Make list of Components of certain type
     * @param {[]} list
     * @param {Number} itemType
     * @return {any} items
     */
    static makeListOfTypedItems(list: [], itemType: string): any {
        console.log(list);
        console.log(itemType);
        const items = [];
        list.forEach((item, key) => {
            const subjectPartComponent = React.createElement('Package', {key: key, data: item}, itemType);
            items.push(subjectPartComponent);
        });
        return items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use strings are they are not treed shakable. Here is a type-safe solution.

```
export type TypedItems = Package | Theme | Part | Knowledges;

export class SubjectDashboardUtils {
    static makeListOfTypedItems<T extends TypedItems>(list: any[], itemType: {new(): T; }): (T)[] {
        console.log(list);
        console.log(itemType);
        const items = [];
        return list.map((data, key) => {
            return React.createElement(itemType, {key, data})
        });
    }
}


// Use it like so

const packages = SubjectDashboardUtils.makeListOfTypedItems(['data'], Package);
const parts = SubjectDashboardUtils.makeListOfTypedItems(['data'], Part);
```

The benefit of this is inheriting type safety. You could probably even have a type of `list` not being any, but for that, I do not know enough of React.

Comment: I am unable to make this work :/ especially part with export type.... I am getting this error ``` Argument of type 'typeof Package' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Package' ```

Comment: ```Type 'typeof Package' is missing the following properties from type 'ThemePartKnowledge': state, componentDidUpdate, render, context, and 4 more.  TS```

Comment: I have updated the types, I had an error there for a minute or two

Answer (score 0):

`React.createElement` needs the component class/function to create components, not a string. Strings are only for creating DOM elements, and those must start with a lowercase letter.

Do this instead:

```
import Package from '...';

React.createElement(Package, ...);
```

If you need to parameterize the creation of elements, you can just pass component types around like any other variable. For example, if you wanted to change `makeListOfTypedItems` to use a dynamic component type, it could look something like this (sorry, don't get your original code's intent, so they might not be what you meant):

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';

// ...

export class SubjectDashboardUtils {
  static makeListOfTypedItems<
    DataType, 
    Cmp extends ComponentType<{ data: DataType }>
  >(list: Array<DataType>, DynamicComponent: Cmp) {
    return list.map((item, key) => <DynamicComponent key={key} data={item}/>);
  }
}
```

This would be called like:

```
SubjectDashboardUtils.makeListOfTypedItems(items, Package);
```

Comment: This is not solving my problem. in method above i am getting itemType by parameter. This is string (Package,Theme,Part,Knowledge) and i have to create component with this string

Comment: is there any other way how to do this?

Comment: i know i could use switch but i hoped there is better way

Comment: Why do you have to create with a string? Can't you pass the component type as a parameter instead?

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but something like my edit could work